# Delete Used Text Line Or Start From "X" Line Next Run?

Tags: python

My Code:

```
       with open('holiday.txt') as fp:
            for category, url in csv.reader(fp):
                 ...code....
                 ...code....
Now I'm Done With This Line. Delete / Or Skip Next Time
```

If the script finished all the code it means I don't need this line of text anymore and next time I just want to skip this line, By deleting it or skipping it if possible it's a cronjob script so any solution that works Is great!

Comment: Please fix your indentation. You refer to a line outside the scope of which that line has meaningful existence. Please also explain exactly what you are trying to do. Does `holiday.txt` only ever contain one line of code?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget holiday.txt contains a lot of lines, Not sure about your indentation issue? it's just part of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic way to do this that I know of, but you could keep track of what lines where already processed in a separate file and then use that if it exists to skip over them on subsequent runs. Here's an outline of what I mean:

```
import csv
import os

processed_lines = set()
if os.path.exists('processed_lines.txt'):
    with open('processed_lines.txt') as lines_fp:
        processed_lines.update(int(line_no) for line_no in lines_fp)

with open('processed_lines.txt', 'a') as lines_fp, \
     open('holiday.txt', 'rb') as fp:
    for line_no, (category, url) in enumerate(csv.reader(fp), 1):
        if line_no not in processed_lines:
            # process the line
            # ...
            lines_fp.write(str(line_no)+'\n')  # add it to processed lines file
```

Answer (score 0):

After you are done with the file completely just wipe it clean.

Much easier then rewriting the file on every line read.

Comment: well if I get an error or something in the middle of running the script lets say at line 500. The next run will do it all over again :) I really need to remove or skip it after I done the important stuff with it :)

Comment: @PeakDermutag there is no real way to do that. Just look in the actual file for the error and remove the line, or add try/catch blocks in your code.

Comment: @qwertni well I thought some saving mechanism will be nice like save to other text file the number of the line it was on and if I start the script it checks last line that it was on?